# Is, android application is develop in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I have a Android application project but i don't know how to start. In how many ways can an adroid application could be develop?.  What are the steps to be taken while developing the application? Is it possible to develop in Xamarin? And what are the steps are involved while implementing a project???

Comment: Not the best question for stack overflow. Short answer: yes, xamarin works, maybe look at android studio. Just try stuff out and ask any concrete questions you have while you develop

Comment: Have you already developed anything for android? What's the scope of the project?

Comment: *"And what are the steps are involved while implementing a project?"* Do you have *any* relevant experience?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can develop android application with Xamarin but can you provide us more info about what specificly your skills are like do you know programming languages like c# etc or you are just a beginner and want to learn..